# How to add column indices in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have a text file with a number of rows and columns like this:

```
a b c d ...  
e f g h ...  
i j k l ...  
...
```

I want to add column indices for each entry with the output look like this

```
1:a 2:b 3:c 4:d ...  
1:e 2:f 3:g 4:h ...  
1:i 2:j 3:k 4:l ...  
...
```

I am wondering if there is a simple way to realize this in bash. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf i":"$i" "};printf "\n"}' file
```

Output:

```
1:a 2:b 3:c 4:d 5:... 
1:e 2:f 3:g 4:h 5:... 
1:i 2:j 3:k 4:l 5:... 
1:...
```

Comment: If one of the fields contains `%`, you'll get funny results this way. Use `printf("%d:%s ", i, $i)` or so instead of `printf i":"$i" "` to avoid that problem. Also note that this makes all lines end with a spurious space character, which may or may not be a problem. One way around that is `awk '{for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) { $i = sprintf("%d:%s", i, $i) }; print }'`, i.e. replacing the fields instead of printing directly.

Comment: Thank you for your useful hints.

Answer (score 1):

With perl:

```
perl -lane '$, = " "; print map { (1 + $_) . ":$F[$_]" } 0 .. $#F' file
# or
perl -lane '$, = " "; $i = 1 ; print map { $i++ . ":$_" } @F' file
```